# How to implement checkmark buttons in iPad out side of tableview

Tags: ios, ipad, uibutton, checkmark

How to implement custom checkmark buttons depends on array count, and need to allow multiple selection in those buttons. Currently I'm used like this,

```
int YAxis = 300;
for (int x=0; x< [myResultArray count];x++) 
{
    checkmarkButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    checkmarkButton.frame = CGRectMake(100, YAxis, 20, 20);
    checkmarkButton.tag = selectedServiceTag;
    [self.view addSubview:checkmarkButton];YAxis = YAxis+30;
}
```

Setting images for check mark:

```
    [checkmarkButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBox_none"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [checkmarkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(serviceSelected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

then I had implement the action method.

```
     -(void)serviceSelected
     {
         checkmarkButton.selected = !checkmarkButton.selected;
         if (checkmarkButton.selected)
         {
             [checkmarkButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBox"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         }
         else
         {
             [checkmarkButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBox_none"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         }
     }
```

But, at the time of selecting only last index button is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

check your image extension png or jpg

```
 -(IBAction)serviceSelected:(id)sender
    {
     UIButton *tmpYes = (UIButton *)sender;

        if (tmpYes.currentBackgroundImage==[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBox.png"]) {

          [tmpYes setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBox_none.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        }
        else
        {
           [tmpYes setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkBox_none.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];



        }
    }
```